# Azure B2C redirect url not working when using server address

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have setup following as redirect URI's under registered app:

1. https://localhost:44332
2. https://myserver.com/v1/myapp

When I run the app locally and using localhost redirect URI, click on "signin/signup" its redirecting to b2c login page and successfully redirects to localhost.

But if I run app where its deployed "https://myserver.com/v1/myapp" and uses https://myserver.com/v1/myapp as redirect URI, and click on "signin/signup" it just reloads same page and not redirects to b2c login page.

I have tried to debugged same scenario and if uses https://myserver.com/v1/myapp my breakpoint doesnt hit "OnAuthorizationCodeReceived" but works as expected when uses localhost as redirect uri.

Basically I want user to browse app as https://myserver.com/v1/myapp, click on "Signin/Signup", provide b2c credentials and rediects back to https://myserver.com/v1/myapp as a logged in user.

what I missing here if redirecting users to server address instead localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue, it was due to mismatch reply uri (under app registration) and RedirectUri setup in web.config. These uri should match exactly once I have modified its able to redirect to b2c login page.